# Spring actuator : How to use customised path check the health

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using spring actuator with spring boot for check my service's health.I am using openJdk11. And using:

Spring-boot dependency:

```
'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
```

Actuator dependency:

```
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.1.6.RELEASE'
```

While this is working fine, means as I try http://localhost:9000/actuator/health from the browser,getting back:

[image]

**I need to get the same response back with :**

```
http://localhost:9000/health
```

**Is there way to do that?**

Please let me know if more clarification is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot Actuator auto-configures all enabled endpoints to be exposed over HTTP. The default convention is to use the *id* of the endpoint with a prefix of `/actuator` as the URL path. For example, health is exposed as `/actuator/health.`

For example, your application might already use `/actuator` for another purpose. You can use the `management.endpoints.web.base-path` property to change the prefix for your management endpoint

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/manage
```

The preceding *application.properties* example changes the endpoint from `/actuator/{id} to /manage/{id}` (for example, `/manage/health`).

Answer (score 1):

By setting the property `management.endpoints.web.base-path`.
Read more in section 54.1 in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html)